# Weyl's equidistribution theorem in the case of rational numbers

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, ergodic-theory

Let θ be a non-zero real number and let N be a positive integer. Consider the fractional parts of nθ for 0 ≤ n < N. This creates a maximum of N possible intervals. Show that there as only three possible length of this interval. I have no idea how to do this problem. It looks so simple but I am really unable to proof it. So any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How do the fractional parts of $n\theta$ create even _one_ interval? Can you illustrate with an example?

Comment: $\theta = 0.3$, $N = 5$, fractional parts are $0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.2$. Three intervals that have different lengths are $(0,0.2), (0.2,0.3), (0.3,0.6)$.

Comment: It's like suppose $\theta=\frac{3}{10}$ then and $N=3$. Then there possible interval will be $(0,\frac{3}{10}),(\frac{3}{10},\frac{6}{10})and (\frac{6}{10},1)$. That's what I think so

Comment: The title is not good.

Comment: $\theta=0.3$ and $\theta=\tfrac{3}{10}$ are one and the same... How is it possible if $\theta=\sqrt{2}$ and $N=100$ for example ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Ran a program for $\theta = \sqrt 2$ and $N=100$, the three distinct interval lengths (up to 8 decimal places) are `5.05063e-3,7.14267e-3,1.219331e-2`. `7.14267e-3` happens in one interval only and is approximately the length of interval $(0, 99\sqrt 2\bmod 1) = (0, 99\sqrt 2 - 140)$. Also the shorter two lengths add up to the third.

Comment: Yes you are right. For any N the fractional part always will belong to $[0,1]$. The problem looks quite simple from that way. Anyone has any solutions. I have been thinking for two days almost.

Comment: Anyone has any idea how to do it. I have a partial solution, but can't come it fully

Comment: This is the Steinhaus Three-Gap Theorem, which see.

Comment: By the way, it has nothing to do with Weyl equidistribution. Weyl says nothing about the number of different lengths of intervals. A sequence of reals can be equidistributed and have many more than three gap lengths (for initial segments).

Comment: Ohhh thanks sir. I have been searching it for 4 days and I had no idea how to do it. Closest thing I saw is they are equidistribruted which gave me a hint that I am looking at the problem entirely different. And hence over here

Comment: Can you provide any good link to the proof sir. It will be helpful

Comment: The possibilities seem to be at the start, in the middle, and at the end.

Comment: There is a paper in exactly in this topic by Noel B. Slater Gaps and steps for the secquence $n\theta$ mod$1$. Can anyone provide me any link so that I can read the paper

Comment: Just type "three gaps" and Steinhaus into the internet, and see what comes back to you.